# Union all within subquery

Tags: sql, sql-server

I need some assistance in getting the following solution.

I have a case when statement that when a value is a specific number, I need it to return a certain number of union all results. Query example below.

For example, `if T0.Docnum = 1` I need it to return 3 rows of 9's.

Obviously when I run the query below I get the error that the subquery returns more than one result. I am out of ideas at this point.

Any ideas are appreciated.

I am using SSMS and SQL Server 2016.

Thanks

```
select 
    case 
        when cast(count(T0.Docnum) as nvarchar(max)) = 1 
           then (select '999' 
                 union all
                 select '999'
                 union all
                 select '999'
                 union all
                 select '999'
                 union all
                 select '999') 

         when cast(count(T0.docnum) as nvarchar(max)) = 2 
             then (select '999' 
                   union all
                   select '999'
                   union all
                   select '999'
                   union all
                   select '999')

         when cast(count(T0.docnum) as nvarchar(max)) = 3 
             then (select '999' 
                   union all
                   select '999'
                   union all
                   select '999')
     end
```

Comment: Knowing which DBMS you're using (and what version) will be helpful for answerers to know what SQL can be used to solve the problem. Please update your question with this info. Thanks!

Comment: Why on earth are you casting a number (result of count) to string (nvarchar) then comparing it to a number???

Comment: The CASE expression in SQL evaluates to a scalar value, not a result set of rows. You are trying to use the CASE expression sort of like an IF statement in a language like Python or Java. That's not how SQL works.

Comment: Your description is that when `count(docnum) = 1` then you need to return three rows, but your code snippet returns Five rows for that scenario?

Comment: It is part of a union all, the only way I could get it to flow was by converting it back to a varchar. Apologies for the confusion in my example, it could be if count(docnum) = 1 then return 5 rows of 9's.

Answer (score 1):

A simple way to 'generate' additional rows is with CROSS APPLY

(AFTER the GROUP BY, which I do in a sub-query...)

```
SELECT
  *
FROM
(
  SELECT
    X,
    Y,
    COUNT(TO.docnum)   AS doc_count
  FROM
    something
  GROUP BY
    X,
    Y
)
  AS foo
CROSS APPLY
(
  SELECT '999' AS generated
  UNION ALL
  SELECT '999' WHERE doc_count IN (3,2,1)
  UNION ALL
  SELECT '999' WHERE doc_count IN (2,1)
  UNION ALL
  SELECT '999' WHERE doc_count IN (1)
)
  AS bar
```

Returns 1 row, always.
Returns a second row if doc_count is 1, 2 or 3.
Returns a third row if doc_count is 1 or 2
Returns a fourth row if doc_count is 1

EDIT : reply to comment.

```
CROSS APPLY
(
  SELECT '999' AS generated
  UNION ALL
  SELECT '999' WHERE doc_count IN (5,3,2,1)
  UNION ALL
  SELECT '999' WHERE doc_count IN (5,2,1)
  UNION ALL
  SELECT '999' WHERE doc_count IN (5,1)
  UNION ALL
  SELECT '999' WHERE doc_count IN (5)
)
```

All five rows match the scenario where doc_count = 5, so it generates five rows.

But only four rows match the scenario where doc_count = 1, so that would generate four rows.

Comment: Thanks, I will take a look at this.

Comment: Thanks for sharing. I think I will be able to get what I need. Question - how in the logic can I tell it to generate 5 rows if the doc_count = 5? Sorry Just a little confused. Thanks.

Comment: @swetts - make the CROSS APPLY function return five rows, but add WHERE clauses to them all. For the first row, make the where clause match all scenarios where you want one OR MORE rows. For the second row, make the WHERE clause match all scenarios where you want two OR MORE rows. And so on.

Comment: thank you! I was able to get it to work. Now I just have to make it work as part of an existing union all. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Check this fiddle and see if it helps you.  I have used a variable to simulate your condition.  I wasn't exactly sure what your logic was for determining the number of rows.

I use a CTE to generate an arbitrary number of rows, then select 999 from it.

https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2016&fiddle=cbaf378f43139dc47c2bcc1f1190442d

```
DECLARE @docnum INT;
SET @docnum = 1;

WITH r AS (
    SELECT 1 AS n
    UNION ALL
    SELECT n+1 FROM r WHERE n+1<= 
      CASE WHEN @docnum = 3 then 1
        when @docnum = 2 then 2
        when @docnum = 1 then 3 end
)
SELECT 999 FROM r;
```

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. The logic is just harcoded.

Comment: For example, if the count = 1 then return 5 rows of 9's, if the count = 2 return 4 rows of 9's, if the count = 3 then 3 rows of 9's... not my logic unfortunately but I'm trying to get it to work!

Comment: Sure.  See that CASE statement?  Change that to match your hardcoded logic.

Comment: For instance, you would say WHEN count(T0.Docnum) = 1 THEN 5 WHEN count(T0.Docnum) = 2 THEN 4 ... etc, until you have all your conditions in.  I just used a variable because I didn't have the actual table to select against.

Comment: Ok this makes alot of sense. Thank you. Only thing I am trying to work with is figuring out how to set the declare to my current query where I am pulling the doc count from. Thanks!

Comment: You mean `DECLARE @docnum INT`?  That's not necessary.  I just declared a variable to hold an INT for the purpose of demoing the query.  In your implementation you would replace the `@docnum` variable with count(T0.Docnum).  I just used a variable for convenience.

Comment: The OP is asking how to generalise this to work against a set, rather than a scalar.  For example, if there was a CTE preceding this, which took the form `SELECT X, COUNT(Y) AS COUNT_Y FROM foo GROUP BY X`, how would the OP generate extra rows based on each input row's value in COUNT_Y?

Comment: Is there a CTE preceding this which takes the form SELECT X, COUNT(Y) AS COUNT_Y FROM foo GROUP BY X?  There wasn't a lot of extra information in the question.

Comment: It seems like a little more explanation of the actual use would help.  It seems like there's a few ways to go about it, depending on what he's trying to do.  For instance, I could just select the count into the variable.  https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2016&fiddle=8243f0a907ca780b394cfaf29847d753

Comment: I went back and reread the question and the comments on it.  Is he trying to just return a fixed number of rows in the result set.  Like the 999s are just padding?  Still not sure.

Comment: @swetts - one possible generalisation... https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2016&fiddle=5549a6f19b296e75153cd0d6e4bd4e1a